# Browsing mapped network drives in Aptana Studio - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

I've recently started using Windows 7 (64-bit) at work, but after installing Aptana like usual, and mapping my network folders like I always have, Aptana shows the mapped drives, but with a red X on the drive icon. Using the native windows explorer I can browse the drives fine, and I don't need to login.

If it matters the mapped drives are hosted on both Windows and Linux servers.

Any ideas on what to do? My googling is drawing blanks.

Comment: I created a question about this on stackoverflow a couple months back, however haven't gotten an answer yet. I have a ticket open at http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3146

Answer (score 0):

I would assume your Aptana Studio does not run with the same privileges as the ones used to map the network drive.

I currently have 2 mapped network shares. One is a SharePoint library and one is a file share. I have both mapped using my domain user account credentials. When opening Aptana Studio, both mapped locations show up fine and are accessible.

When I start my Aptana Studio "as Administrator", I instantly get the situation you describe (both mapped network location shown with a red "X" and not accessible).

So I would assume that you either have to adjust your network share mappings or the user account you run Aptana Studio as.